# a chain rule problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

[image]

I know how to apply chain rule but I have no clue how to apply chain rule in this problem
Please guide me.
I actually am confused how to even start

[image]

Comment: calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ of $f(x,y,z,w)=0$  and the same for $g$

Comment: I tried but not able to match any options as given

Comment: please add them to your post.

Comment: OK I am editing my post

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: You sould do you formulas in [Latex and not using pictures](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). 
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is `\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}` and $f_x$ is `f_x`. 
In the two left lines of your calculation you can replace $f_x$ and $g_x$ by $0$ and then try to eliminate $w_x$ by multiplying the equations by appropriate factors and subtracting them.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get your point please guide me....

Comment: Please transform your post to Latex. I see now that the derivates you calculated are wrong.